# Android Menu Layout Front page

Tags: java, android, layout, yelp

I want to make a menu sort of similar to [Yelps front page](http://mobiputing.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/yelp-2.0-android.jpg).

The left image in particular. I feel like I've seen this on multiple apps, and I also remember thinking that this was actually something built into the default android layouts, but I can't seem to find anything on it anywhere.

How would I go about making this layout? Is there something already built for you, or do I have to make using image buttons and a relative layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ also uses something like this on their first page; a lot of apps do now. It's called a dashboard layout. You can see an overview of that [here](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/02/ui-design-pattern-dashboard.html) and an explanation of how to create it [here](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/build-dashboard-ui-for-android/).

Answer (score 0):

Using button images and a relative layout is an easy way to do this. For help on that look at this tut: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html